# Erron on file.Save() 'Size is less than zero'

Tags: c#, taglib, wma

I just created a little program which allows me to change the details of an audio file.

I want to change:

- Title
- AlbumArtist
- Performers
- Album
- Picture

The taglib library allows me to change different kinds of audio files with the exact same code.

For me, the following code works completely fine with the extensions `.m4a` and `mp3`, but as soon as I tried to also change some `.wma` files, a strange error occured.

```
public void changeAttributes(string filePath, string title, string interpret, string album)
{
    TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(filePath);

    file.Tag.Title = title;                                 //Titel
    file.Tag.AlbumArtists = new String[] {interpret};       //AlbumArtist
    file.Tag.Performers = new String[] { interpret };       //Performers
    if (!album.Equals("")) { file.Tag.Album = album; }      //Album (if there is no album given, it won´t be overwritten)

    if (!albumCoverPath.Equals("")) {
        file.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[] { (IPicture)new Picture(albumCoverPath) };
    }   //Album-Cover (if there is no image given, it won´t be overwritten)

    file.Save();
}
```

Once I put the three `.wma-files` into the folder I was testing in, The code stopped and got me into the debugger at the line `file.Save();` with the error

**System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Size is less than zero."**

When checking the `file`-object in the debugger I can´t find anything that would explain the occurrence of the error.

**EDIT:**

Once I removed the line which changes the `AlbumArtists`, the Code runs just fine.

And after once changing everything but the `AlbumArtists`, I can insert the line of code again and it runs without errors.
Can anyone tell me how this strange behavior came about?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm doing some research to make sure WMA are supported but I'm unable to find a safe result. Sorry about the answer

Comment: I couldn't find anything regarding to this seither. But thaks anyway, all help is appreciated.

Comment: @TimSchmidt, did you ever figure out what the problem is here?  I just ran into this issue by doing this `$tag = [TagLib.File]::Create($file.FullName); $tag.tag.title = $newTitle; $tag.Save()` and got the error you referenced.

Comment: As a follow-up, I ended up using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028384/1253609) to fix the issue above.

Comment: @incutonet No, I decided that I dont´care ^^ but good to see that you solved your problem, also thanks for providing the link to the solution you used.