# Update a song metadata with taglib-sharp and Powershell

Tags: powershell, metadata, taglib-sharp

I am trying to update a song metadata with `taglib-sharp` and `powershell`.
It works fine for most of the files but there are errors on some `wma` files (I can play these files though).

```
# Load the tag-lib assembly
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( (Resolve-Path ("D:\zic\lib\taglib-sharp.dll")))

# Load up the song file and its metadata
$path_file="‪D:\zic\misc\Artist_Title.wma"
$song = [TagLib.File]::Create((resolve-path $path_file))
$file_name = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($path_file) 
$file_name_array=$file_name.Split("_")
$artist=$file_name_array[0]
$title=$file_name_array[1]

#set the artist and title (metadata)
$song.Tag.Artists = $artist 
$song.Tag.AlbumArtists = $artist 
$song.Tag.Title = $title

# Save the metadata 
$song.Save()
```

The error appears when the file is saved:
[image]

Is it a `powershell` problem? A `taglib-sharp` problem?
I am using `taglib_sharp` version 2.0.50727 and `powershell` version 5.1.16299.248.

---

**EDIT**

With a try catch to show the error:

```
# Save the metadata
try
{
    $song.Save() 
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception|format-list -force
}
```

The console displays:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

If I edit the tags manually (right click on the file -> properties) or rename the file, the program runs without problem and the tags are updated. Weird!

Comment: Like a problem with `taglib-sharp`. Inspect `$Error[0].Exception.StackTrace` to see where in the code this all falls down

Comment: I just edited my post with the trace.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the files aren't actually named `Artist_Artists.wma` right? Look at the actual file name of one of the files which throws an exception, and of one which doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @tukan suggested, the length of some tags was the problem.

Let's display all the tags of a song:

```
$song = [TagLib.File]::Create((resolve-path $path_file))
foreach ($tag in $song.Tag)
{
    Write-Host "tag:" $tag
}
```

The output:

```
tag:
tag: {D1607DBC-E323-4BE2-86A1-48A42A28441E}
tag: 10.00.00.3802
tag: 0.0.0.0000
tag: 0
tag: 2007
tag: 128317523430000000
tag: AMGa_id=R  1411185;AMGp_id=VA;AMGt_id=T 14593744
tag: Éri Tabuhci
tag: Universal
tag: World
tag: Les 100 Plus Grands Tubes Disc 3
tag: Unknown Artist
tag: 14+96+34B7+ADE8+E42D+11DF5+15230+196F2+1C2D1+1FC01+257E9+29612+2D100+30FB0+34ECE+3923F+3D39B+40CF6+454FF+49162+4D5D0+521B0
tag: AMG
tag: World
tag: 5
```

The fourth tag from the end is too long and is the cause of the problem.
The solution is to load the file, **remove all the existing tags**, save it, load it again and then set the tags you want.
For example:

```
$song = [TagLib.File]::Create((resolve-path $path_file))
$song.RemoveTags($song.TagTypes)
$song.Save()

$song = [TagLib.File]::Create((resolve-path $path_file))
$song.Tag.Artists = "blabla"
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked out! I hope the solution will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

My guess based on the [source code](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/blob/b1155885656c9625c2cc6d928b9329e2a5206048/src/TagLib/ByteVector.cs) is that you reached a ByteVector size (probably file size or some list) limit which is [2,147,483,647](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int) - int overflow.

If the filesize of the `.wma` files or list is greater than `2,147,483,647` byte(s) you will get to the negative numbers (overflow) and thus getting this exception.

You have to open a ticket on github with this project and they should use the `long` type there which has limit `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

When you edit manually you don't get to this limit so it works.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem of file size, The files are quite small, between 2 and  5 MB.

Comment: @rom then it is the some inner list you are trying to update.  Could you list the `$song.Tag.* ` of the bogus `.wma` files?

Comment: Thanks, as you suggested, the length of some tags was the problem. I am going to post my solution.